# Use of backreferences in fail2ban filters possible?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

From time to time, I see collections of suspect "File not found" errors in my Apache logs, basically using the pattern

```
File does not exist: /var/www/file, referer: http://my.server.com/file
```

In human terms: The file was not found, though it referenced here itself. A clear hacking attempt, as that's hardly possible (and the `REQUEST_URI`s often enough suggest the same). In my eyes a clear case for `fail2ban` – if I could get backreferences to work here:

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s File does not exist: /var/www(.+), referer: http://.+\1$
```

(Justin Case: above examples assume the `DIRECTORY_ROOT` of that webserver being `/var/www`)

I googled for hours, searched the [fail2ban wiki](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/) up and down – but nowhere I could find a statement concerning backreferences in its filters. Are they not supported, or did I do it the wrong way? Any hints how to make it work (except from "dirty hacks" like first sending the request to another fake url using [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite), and then catching on that (if anyone is interested, I can elaborate on that approach in an answer), or doing something similar using [mod-security](/questions/tagged/mod-security))?

---

as an entire log line was requested:

```
[Fri Nov 08 14:57:28 2013] [error] [client 50.67.234.213] File does not exist: /var/www/text/files.htm++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+using+proxy+27.34.142.47:9090;+no+post+sending+forms+are+found;, referer: http://www.myserver.com/text/files.htm++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+using+proxy+27.34.142.47:9090;+no+post+sending+forms+are+found;
```

<sup>(sorry, logs were just switched, so this long candidate was the only one left *currently*; minor adjustments were made for privacy reasons)</sup>

Comment: Would you post an entire line from the log?

Comment: Sure. Just added one to the end of my question. Though it adds no new information: except for the different file path, it's just prefixed with the default Apache Error log information which looks the same with each Apache install ;)

Comment: fail2ban uses normal python regexes, so backreferences should work. Do you get a regex compilation error or do things simply not match? What does `fail2ban-regex` say?

Comment: That's exactly the thing. I've checked the regex, and it works *outside* fail2ban. `fail2ban-regex` simply finds no hits. I tried to narrow it down: `fail2ban-regex` shows matches if I leave the trailing `\1$` off the line; but as soon as I add those 3 chars (or just the `\1`), no more hits.

Comment: Just for the records: seems not to be a "hacker", but rather a SEO tool behind those requests (see e.g. [here](http://www.blackhatteam.com/f130/what-is-the-solution-32622.html)). Still, those are not welcome visitors for some of us ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the backreference numbering is a bit wacky.  Try using a [Named Group](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) ... something like this:

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s File does not exist: /var/www(?P<snoop_file>.+), referer: http://.+(?P=snoop_file)$
```

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. Be gone, ya SEO crawlers :) And big thanks, rick (+1 & accepted)!